# PendingIntent.getBroadcats don't find an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm writing an application with multiple alarms and I want to have an option to cancel them. I'm using AlarmManager and PendingIntent. My problem is that when I want to cancel an alarm, getBroadcast don't find a PendingIntent matching the criteria.

```
private void turnOnMorningRemider()
    {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 45;

        Intent tmpIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmPopUpDialog.class);

        tmpIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.alarm_time_of_day), AlarmPopUpDialog.REQUEST_CODE_MORNING);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(tmpIntent);

        // Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        morningPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(AlarmPopUpDialog.REQUEST_CODE_MORNING, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        //set the alarm for particular time
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, morningPendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is on.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

To cancel alarm I use:

```
private void turnOffMorningReminder()
{
    Intent tmpIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmPopUpDialog.class);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmPopUpDialog.REQUEST_CODE_MORNING,
            tmpIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

    if  (pi != null)
    {
        alarmManager.cancel(pi);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is off.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The pi variable is always null, so alarm starts ringing.

The next problem is, when I try to create PendingIntent with getBroadcast (instead of stack builder)  my alarm never activates.

```
morningPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmPopUpDialog.REQUEST_CODE_MORNING, tmpIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Is using the stack builder the reason why i can't find the intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel stupid. My problem was that my AlarmPopUpDialog extended Activity not BroadcastReceiver class. When I added a class that extened BroadcastReceiver in the middle everything started to work.

```
morningPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmBrodcastReceiver.REQUEST_CODE_MORNING, tmpIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmPopUpDialog.class );
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtras(intent);
        context.startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

I hope that this answer will help the next poor guy.